# Leading of FontMetrics seems that returns always zero?

Tags: android, fontmetrics

I tried this code:

```
Paint.FontMetrics pf = new Paint.FontMetrics();
parentPaint.getFontMetrics(pf);
float lead = pf.leading;
```

But it seems that leading is always `0`.I read docs in about `leading`:

> The recommended additional space to add between lines of text.

But I do not know what it means. Can any one help me to understand what it means? Any image can help better.

Answer (score 0):

use "-(pm.top - pm.ascent) + (pm.bottom - pm.descent)" instead .

I print some result in an example .

```
01-28 06:14:40.046: E/pm(4250): ----->descent=6.8359375  ascent=-25.976563 leading=0.0 bottom=7.5878906 top=-29.339844
01-28 06:14:40.046: E/pm space leading(4250): -----> 4.1152344
```